# Can't reach postgres container from app container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-composer.yml that is setting up two services: `server` and `db`. The Node.js server, which is the `server` service, uses `pg` to connect to the PostgreSQL database; and the `db` service is a PostgreSQL image.

On the server startup, it tries to connect to the database but gets a timeout.

---

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: myapi
    build: .
    container_name: server
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:15432/mydb
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: node script.js
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - 15432:15432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: -p 15432
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  db-data:
```

*Edit: code above changed to remove `links` and `expose`.*

---

`db` service output:

```
db        | 
db        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db        | 
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.865 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.865 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 15432
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.865 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 15432
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.873 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.15432"
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.880 UTC [25] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-05 20:18:12 UTC
db        | 2020-11-05 20:18:15.884 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

---

`script.js` - used by the command from the `server` service.

```js
const pg = require('pg');

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 5000,
});
pool.connect((err, _, done) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    done(err);
  }
  done();
});
pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res);
  pool.end();
});

const client = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 5000,
});
client.connect(console.error);
client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res);
  client.end();
});
```

`server` service output:

*NOTE: The first line is the output of the first `console.log` call from `script.js`.*

*NOTE: Since the `server` service is set up with `restart: unless-stopped`, it will repeat this output forever.*

```
server    | postgres://postgres:postgres@db:15432/mydb
server    | Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
server    |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)
server    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
server    |     at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:78:10)
server    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at emitCloseNT (net.js:1659:8)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)
server    |     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
server    |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:523:9)
server    |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
server    | Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
server    |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)
server    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
server    |     at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:78:10)
server    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at emitCloseNT (net.js:1659:8)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)
server    |     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
server    |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:523:9)
server    |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) undefined
server    | Error: timeout expired
server    |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:95:26)
server    |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
server    |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
server    | Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
server    |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)
server    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
server    |     at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:78:10)
server    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
server    |     at emitCloseNT (net.js:1659:8)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21) undefined
server    | postgres://postgres:postgres@db:15432/mydb
...
```

---

From the host computer, I can reach the PostgreSQL database at the `db` service, **connecting successfully**, using the same script from the `server` service.

The output of the script running from the host computer:

```js
➜  node script.js
postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:15432/mydb
null Client { ... }
undefined Result { ... }
null Result { ... }
```

This output means the connection succeeded.

---

#### In summary:

I can't reach the `db` container from the `server` container, getting timeouts on the connection, but I can reach the `db` container from the host computer, connecting successfully.

---

#### Considerations

First, thanks for the answer so far. Addressing some points raised:

- **Missing network:**

  It isn't required because docker-compose has a default network. A tested with a custom network but it didn't work either.
- **Order of initialization:**

  I'm using `depends_on` to ensure the `db` container is started first but I know it isn't ensuring the database is in fact initialized first then the server. It isn't the problem because the server breaks when a timeout happens and it runs again because it is set up with `restart: unless-stopped`. So if the database is still initializing on the first or second try to start the server, there is no problem because the server will continue to be restarted until it succeeds in the connection (which never happened.)
- **UPDATE:**

  From the `server` container, I could reach the database at the `db` service using `psql`. I still can't connect from the Node.js app there.

  The `DATABASE_URL` isn't the problem because the URI I used in the `psql` command is the same URI used by the `script.js` and printed by the first `console.log` call there.

  Command-line used:

  ```
  docker exec -it server psql postgres://postgres:postgres@db:15432/mydb
  ```

*Edit: Improved code by removing the dependency for Sequelize. Now it uses only `pg` and calls the script directly.*

Comment: it's a long time I didn't use docker, but maybe try to add :
networks:
    - mynetwork
At the same level as port inside server and db services

Comment: Your docker-compose file looks okay, maybe a missing network. Did you try with default postgres port ?

Comment: @Nico docker-compose uses a default network when none is set up, but I tested with a network as you said and it didn't work either.

Comment: @NelsonG. Yes, I tested with the default port too and it didn't work. At first, I thought it was conflicting with the PostgreSQL instance installed on the host computer, but then I changed the port to 15432 instead and it didn't work either.

Comment: I don't think there is a conflict with default port, docker takes care of isolating it. Your server's logs mention a "database.js" configuration file. Are you sure it not overload env DATABASE_URL ?

Comment: @NelsonG. Yes, you can see by the `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL)` output. The URL is correct.

Comment: Can you remove links section? Its useless and deprecated

Comment: @MilanMarkovic Yes, just did. I added because I was desperately trying to find a solution haha.

Comment: I failed to reproduce your error : I reused your docker-compose file, replaced service `app` by a standard ubuntu image, performed a `docker-compose up` and installed `postgresql-client`. Command `psql -h db -p 15432 -U postgres -W` from app container succeeded ! I recommend you to look at the configuration of Sequelize, maybe an error in connection string.

Comment: @NelsonG. As you can see in the "start up script" mentioned in the question description, it's using `pg` to connect to the database, not Sequelize itself. And by comparing the `server` service output and the output when I run the script on the host machine, we can see that they have a similar structure, changing just the hostname (`db` and `localhost`), but one fails and the other succeeds. I made a mistake by keeping Sequelize related code in the code example, it induced wrong conclusions. Thanks for spending your time helping me!

Comment: @NelsonG. I will try to do the same test you did. I'll install postgres in the `server` container and run `psql` trying to reach the `db` server. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @NelsonG @MateusPires - tried the same as Nelson and I'm having no issue either - I'd also try removing the volume. There is a `pg_hba.conf` in that dir that may contain an old rule that may be blocking access.

Comment: @NelsonG. @jeeves I just tried that and I could reach the `db` container using `psql` from the `server` container. Now I need to find out why I can't reach from the node.js app using `pg`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile. I have taken your docker-compose and script and can't reproduce your problem. I'm using `node:10-alpine` as a base image with no other libs installed other than `pg`

Comment: @jeeves Yes! I just finished creating a simpler version of the project and hosted on GitHub. This project has the same problem: I can't connect to the database from the Node.js app but I can when using `psql`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/mateuspiresl/api-boilerplate-ts-pg-seq-con). 
If you run the app at `master`, you will see it runs without problems. But if go to `dev`, where the containerization was implemented, you will see what I was talking about.

I created a [PR](https://github.com/mateuspiresl/api-boilerplate-ts-pg-seq-con/pull/1) with the containerization implementation.

Comment: @jeeves Just made a even smaller one using `pg` only and I still have the problem, it's [here at branch minimal](https://github.com/mateuspiresl/api-boilerplate-ts-pg-seq-con/tree/minimal).

Comment: Answer updated with solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the source to reproduce the issue.
No issues in the `docker-compose` file as you have already ruled out.

The problem lies between your `Dockerfile` and the version of `node-pg` that you are using.

You are using `node:14-alpine` and `pg: 7.18.2`.
Turns out there is a [bug](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180) on node 14 and earlier versions of `node-pg`.

Solution is either downgrade to node v12 **or** use latest version of `node-pg` which is currently 8.4.2 (fix went in on v8.0.3).

I have verified both these solutions on the branch you provided and they work.

Comment: I added some considerations at the end of the question description. I also tested starting them separately as you said but the problem persisted.

Comment: That's why it worked on the host machine, the node version is 12 there. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer; I don't have your code handy so I can't actually test the compose file. However, there are a few issues there I'd like to point out:

- The `links` directive is deprecated.

  The `links` is a legacy option that was used before Docker introduced user-defined networks and automatic DNS support. You can just get rid of it. Containers in a compose file are able to refer to each other by name without.
- The `expose` directive does nothing. It can be informative in for example a `Dockerfile` as a way of saying, "this image will expose a service on this port", but it doesn't actually make anything happen. It's almost entirely useless in a compose file.
- The `depends_on` directive is also less useful than you would think. It will indeed cause docker-compose to bring up the database container first, but it the container is considered "up" as soon as the first process has started. It doesn't cause docker-compose to wait for the database to be ready to service requests, which means you'll still run into errors if your application tries to connect before the database is ready.

  The best solution to this is to built database re-connection logic into your application so that if the database ever goes down (e.g. you restart the postgres container to activate a new configuration or upgrade the postgres version), the app will retry connections until it is successful.

  An acceptable solution is to include code in your application startup that blocks until the database is responding to requests.

Comment: I added some considerations at the end of the question description regarding the order of initialization. I made a test: I started the `db` container and ensured the database was correctly initialized by reaching it from the host computer, then I started the `server` container, but I got the same output: timeout.

Comment: I will remove the `link` and `expose`, thanks. Regarding that, it's safe to say the port was reachable because I could do it from the host computer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with docker. To test that, perform following actions :

By using this *docker-compose.yml* file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: app
    command: sleep 8h

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    expose:
      - '15432'
    ports:
      - 15432:15432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: -p 15432
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Perform a `docker exec -it app bash` to go into container app then install `postgresql-client` with `apt install -y` postgresql-client`.

Command `psql -h db -p 15432 -U postgres -W` succeeded !

#### Check `pg` configuration

You say that `pg` use environment variable `DATABASE_URL` to reach postgresql. I'm not sure :

From https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting, we can found this example :

```sh
$ PGUSER=dbuser \
  PGHOST=database.server.com \
  PGPASSWORD=secretpassword \
  PGDATABASE=mydb \
  PGPORT=3211 \
  node script.js
```

And this sentence :

> node-postgres uses the same environment variables as libpq to connect to a PostgreSQL server.

In `libpq` documentation, no `DATABASE_URL`.

To adapt example provided in pg documentation with your docker-compose.yml file, try with following file (I only changed environments variables of app service) :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: myapi
    build: .
    container_name: server
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGDATABASE=mydb
      - PGPORT=15432
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: node script.js
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - 15432:15432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: -p 15432
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: I made a "minimal" implementation of my project ([here](https://github.com/mateuspiresl/api-boilerplate-ts-pg-seq-con)), but your idea is better as minimal project. I'll try this and return with any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I created the real minimal project using pg only and I still have the problem, it's [here at branch minimal](https://github.com/mateuspiresl/api-boilerplate-ts-pg-seq-con/tree/minimal). :'(